# Api.ai be public for all not only for tester, developer, admin

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

i have create a bot there but isn't public ...need to be tester to use it...do you know how to do it public for all people without any role as tester or admin or developer ?

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Goto Integration and set URL name for you bot  https://bot.api.ai/yourbotname/

You can give this URL to your tester to test the bot

Comment: Hello @Mohamed which tester , my tester or facebook tester ?